# The product $J^{n}A$ of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $A$ and $J$ are two ideals of a ring $R$. I can't understand the following implication:

If $JA = A$ then $J^{n}A = A$ for all $n > 0$.

True that $J^{n}A$ is an ideal of $A$ for all $n > 0$ and that $A$ has no proper ideals. But how could we draw a contradiction if for some $n$ we would have $J^{n}A = 0$?

Comment: The implication you're asking about doesn't depend on the specific construction of A. You can see that it's true by induction on n.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $J^nA \subseteq A$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Now, $J^n A = J^{n-1}(JA)$, but $(JA) \supseteq A$, so $J^nA \supseteq J^{n-1}A$. Next, $J^{n-1}A = J^{n-2}(JA)$, and as $JA \supseteq A$, we get $J^{n-1}A \supseteq J^{n-2}A$. Hence, $J^nA \supseteq J^{n-1}A \supseteq J^{n-2}A$ and we can continue this process to get the chain:

$$J^nA \supseteq J^{n-1}A \supseteq J^{n-2}A \supseteq \ldots \supseteq J^2 A \supseteq JA \supseteq A$$

so $J^n A \supseteq A$.

Comment: The first inclusion ($J^{n}A \subseteq A$) is clear. How do you construct the chain?

Comment: @Behrooz see the edit. Of course $A$ can be anything satisfying $JA = A$ (nothing has to do with $A$ being a simple module, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

According to what zipirovich said, the induction on $n$ would go as follows:

$P_{1}: \quad JA = A$ (true);

$P_{n}: \quad J^{n}A = A$ (assumption of induction);

$P_{n + 1}: \quad J^{n + 1}A = (JJ^{n})A = J(J^{n}A) = JA = A$, as was to be proved.